# How to render only the first item with FlatList or VirtualizedList in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is my code and it renders all the id from my API fetch json file, i want to render only the first one, its that possible with FlatList ????

```
<FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          keyExtractor={(x, i) => i}
          renderItem={({ item }) =>
            <Text>
              {item.id} 
            </Text>}
        />
      </View>
```

Comment: Why do you need `FlatList` if you just wanna render the first ID ?

Answer (score 0):

You could destructure the first item and use that as your data:

```
const [item] = this.state.data;
return (
    <FlatList
        data={[item]}
        keyExtractor={(x, i) => i}
        renderItem={({ item}) =>  <Text>{item.id}</Text>}
      />
 )
```

If you need to vary the item number for e.g. different questions, you'd need to have the question number as a prop or as part of your state, then do this:

```
const questionIndex = this.state.index;

const currentItem = this.state.data[questionIndex];
return (
    <FlatList
        data={[currentItem]}
        keyExtractor={(x, i) => i}
        renderItem={({item}) =>  <Text>{item.id}</Text>}
      />
 )
```

Though as others have pointed out, a FlatList is intended to be used for a list of items, so if you only need to show a single item you don't need it:

```
const {data, index} = this.state
return (
    <Text>{data[index].id}</Text>
 )
```

Comment: Thank you it works now I have to increment the id for one

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Im coding a Questionnaire thats why I had to render just the first Id. Now I have to render the other questions one by one in the same screen. Do you know how to do it???

Comment: How are you keeping track of your question number?

Comment: `   export default class AnketaScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            text: "",
            index: 0,
 } }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchData();
    }
    fetchData = async () => {
        const response = await fetch("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees");
        const json = await response.json();
        this.setState({ data: json });
    };
    onPress = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({ index: prevState.index + 1 }));
    `

Comment: ` render() {  const barWidth = Dimensions.get("screen").width - 35;
        console.log(this.state.data)
        return ( <View style={{ flex: 1 }}> <View style={styles.container}>
                    <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
                        <FlatList
                       data={this.state.data}
                            keyExtractor={(x, i) => i.toString()}
                            renderItem={({ item, index }) => (index === 0 ? <Text onPress={this.onPress} style={styles.container}>{item.id}{item.employee_name}</Text> : null)}
                        />

Comment: This is my code, i dont know how to get the id of question dynamically from the url in react native ????